# Can I have dll files as wpf modules that are used as TabItems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to make like 5 different wpf files and saving them as a class library and then on runtime use import them into a application and use them as tabs?

So like

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem>
           ----Some imported dll----
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
           ----Some other imported dll----
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You can dynamically import dlls, have a look at MEF (http://mef.codeplex.com/) and/or MAF (http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DanielMoth/Managed-AddIn-Framework)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with

```
    xmlns:TechLog="clr-namespace:TechLog;assembly=TechLog"

                    <TabItem Header="System log">
                        <TechLog:UserControl1></TechLog:UserControl1>
                    </TabItem>
```

TechLog is a WPF User Control Library project that is added to the solution and that outputs a .dll which I wanted

Answer (score 0):

well i assume that in your 5 dlls are somekind of usercontrols or views you wanna display? you should really look into MEF for a wpf plugin system. there are a lot of informations out there. i use MEF alot and its really nice and handy.

btw if not you should specify your question. what does import mean for you.